# Laravel Cannot Access Image Stored in Storage Folder after Uploading in Server

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-5.6

I am trying to upload and retrieve image in my Laravel project. It worked perfectly in my local server, but after uploading in live server, its not working.

I am using nginx.

I have tried `php artisan storage:link` but it says

> The "public/storage" directory already exists

I am using this line to open the stored image in a new page.

```
<a href="{{ url('/storage/images/'.$file->file_name) }}" title="">View</a>
```

If I place mouse on the view button, it shows this link: `my_ip/storage/images/image.png` which I think is correct.

However, clicking the link redirects to homepage.

Comment: checked permissions?

Comment: 777 for storage folder. do I need to set permission somewhere else?

Comment: clear cache it may solve your problem command: php artisan clear:cache

Comment: is it recursively 777 ?

Comment: @yehia yes, recursively...

Comment: @Tayyab cache is cleared

Comment: hmm... but I can access in local server. any way to work around? there must be a way to access stored images in storage folder in live server, right?

Comment: I will try to reproduce your problem. please tell me what OS do you use locally and what on server? I suppose server is ubuntu or some other linux distro

Comment: local is windows 10... server is ubuntu 16.04 with nginx and php 7.2

Comment: Let me know if you need more infor or code I used

Comment: can you access the contents of public folder with your IP?
The URL might be: `your_ip/your_project/public/storage/images/image.png` check your nginx configuration...

Comment: let me try this...

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Did you try:
 `{{ asset('/filepath/from/public' ) }}`
Use `asset()` not `url()`

Comment: Same result. redirected to homepage... :(

Comment: Thank you so much. I already got the issue. I had to delete and re-link storage folder with public folder

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `href` will be correct, but that's not the issue.  The issue is the presence of the file at the location of the link. It's not there, as you're finding.

When you upload, make sure you are not uploading a real directory at `public/storage`.

On your local server, did you, by mistake, create a real directory at `public/storage`?

If you did, you need to know that the **laravel** convention is to store your files in the `storage/app/public` directory in your app directory. 
You don't create the folder `public/storage` yourself. 
You create a symlink to link it to there instead. That way, stuff you put in `storage/app/public`, also appears, because of the symlink, at `public/storage`.

First check your local server follows the laravel convention outlined above (and in the docs), then, after uploading to your server, try the `storage:link` command again, and, so long as you don't have a real directory at `public/storage` anymore, but just a link, it should hopefully work.

Note what I've done here is interpret the error message you were getting about that directory already existing.

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395449/laravel-image-saved-in-storage-folder-not-showing-to-user/55852002#55852002) if you are using Homestead. Instead of creating a storage link on the host computer, you should ssh into Vagrant and create a storage link here.

Comment: I followed the Laravel doc and used `php artisan storage:link` command to create the symbolic link. and ran the command after uploading the app to server... any suggesion?

Comment: Try to find out why the public/storage directory already exists.

Comment: It was there in my local server. I uploaded it as it was. Should I delete and try the link command again?

Comment: I deleted the `public/storage` folder and run `php artisan storage:link` command again. I don't know why but its working. I guess I need to link *public* folder with *storage* each time I upload or install the app in a server.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You could look into creating a composer post-install command if you like, which is a little hook to run after a composer install where you can run short commands like this, so you don't have to run them manually.

Comment: I just deleted the `public/storage` folder which I created mistakenly as you said. After deleting it run the `php artisan storage:lin` and it's working. Thanks @mwal

Answer (score 15):

In case you have uploaded public/storage folder to server and getting error:
The "public/storage" directory already exists.

just delete it with

```
rm -R public/storage
```

and run the command again

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are still stuck on this question, this is what worked for me:

In my case I had to change the APP_URL in .env file to the name of my site. It was defaulted to http://localhost. Once I change it everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once, its trying to get to my "localhost:/storage/...."

I noticed that it's localhost not localhost:8000, just change your env

from

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but had a slightly different resolution than what has already been mentioned here.

In my case, I had run `php artisan storage:link` from the host computer of my Docker solution.  I needed to run it instead from within the context of the Docker container.  A sensible solution, but one that's hard to track down, so I figured I'd share.