# Laravel - Image saved in storage folder not showing to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code to save an image in the storage/app/uploads folder

```
 $image_main = Image::where('property_id', $id)->get();

$file = $request->file('file');
      $destinationPath = 'uploads';
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($file as $file1) {
          $i++;
          $extension = $file1->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $path = $file1->storeAs(
              $destinationPath, $i.time().".".$extension
          );
```

This is my blade file

```
@foreach ($image_main as $images)
        <img src="{{"/storage/app/".$images->filename}}
```

The file saves in the storage/app/uploads folder but it doesn't show to the user, it says file not found. am I to set anything in the filesystems.php file

Comment: If you're using the public or S3 storage you can use `<img src="{{Storage::url("/storage/app/".$images->filename)}} />`

Comment: I am using storage folder

Comment: Storage is not public so the webserver can't serve it

Comment: Ok so what's the solution

Comment: where should i save the file

Comment: You should store it in the public folder

Comment: How should i do that @Rob

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: In addition to the solution here, be aware of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409417/storage-in-laravel-says-symlink-no-such-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510683/laravel-how-to-revert-local-storage-symlink-and-refresh/65384757#65384757

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Laravel storage filesystem is so unique. Any file upload will be stored in the `storage/app/public` directory. To make it accessible in `public` directory, things you need to do is to the create symlink by running the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command will symlinked `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`

Just follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) about how to upload and how to retrieve the file url. I am pretty sure the step you are missing is creating the symlink.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

you have add this line in your .env file

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public
```

after that you need to run this command in your terminal

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and if that's is still not working then you need to call storage directory before your link

```
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->image) }}" width="120px" hight="120px" alt="">
```

Comment: Yes it is very important to add FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public , if this chunck code is missing, the images won't appear...

Answer (score 7):

Your storage folder is not accessible from user.

You must pass by **Storage::url()** method:

```
Storage::url("/storage/app/{$images->filename}")
```

As:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url("/storage/app/{$images->filename}") }}" alt="{{ $images->filename }}" />
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#retrieving-files

Answer (score 5):

After try several solutions I fixed it

1. delete symbolc link
2. rebuild the symbolic link

   ```
    php artisan storage:link
   ```

and it worked again

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `homestead` as the environment on Mac then you need to follow this:

1. Delete your public/storage folder (if any)
2. Follow these steps:

   1. ssh into your homestead using below command
   2. `cd ~homestead`
   3. `vagrant up`
   4. `vagrant ssh`
   5. `cd Code/PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_ROOT_DIR`
   6. `php artisan storage:link`
3. Access image like this `{{ asset('storage/img/myimage.jpg') }}`

Comment: Yes for existing project only

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the storage folder for this. You need to move the images to the public folder to access from http.

Try to create a folder call images in public folder and upload the image to that folder. Then you can access the images as follows.

```
<img src="{{ public_path('images/image-name.png')}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: How can i save them in the public folder

Comment: change your $destinationPath variable as this - $destinationPath = '../images/'; Make sure you have images folder in public folder and it is writable.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem was Solved for me.

Step 1. Delete storage folder in `public/storage` Directory then

Step 2. Run this command `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method it will 100% work.**

First create a symlink : `php artisan storage:link`

Look inside public folder where all of your images are stored and in src mention those folder names and atlast your image name from the database.

Example :

```
<img src="/images/posts/{{$post->featured_image}}">
```

OR

Example : Full path to display image using link in browser

```
<img src="{{asset('/images/posts/'.$post->featured_image)}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (the symlink has been added) with my local environment, but all started working after changing `APP_URL=http://localhost to APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000` in the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing helps like in my case, check your symlink with `ls -l` if you are on linux and pay attention to the path is absolute or relative. Mine was absolute because I switched my dev environment from a local install of php and apache to docker. If you are in the same situation, delete the symlink and create it with this additional parameter:

```
php artisan storage:link --relative
```

Laravel may ask for symfony/filesystem to be installed. Then run this first:

```
composer require symfony/filesystem
```

After the creation of the symlink with the correct path now everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the below line in your .env file

   ```
   FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public (Laravel 9 and below)

   FILESYSTEM_DISK=public (Laravel 10 and above)
   ```
2. Navigate to the public folder and delete the storage link folder
3. Then Run the command

   ```
   php artisan storage:link
   ```